# How To Subtract One Month For Where Clause In Db2

Tags: razor, db2

How to display the last one month result in where clause statement in DB2.

```
This is my query:-
SELECT distinct
payment_date dated_daily
FROM  payment BB 
WHERE  YEAR(payment_date)= '2018'
AND MONTH(payment_date) = '04'
```

Say I have the following Column

```
dated_daily
2018-04-01
until
2018-04-30
```

After subtract

```
dated_daily
2018-03-01
until
2018-03-31
```

Anyone can help me?. Thank you

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. What is the result you are looking for? What is the problem?

Comment: @data_henrik thank you for response. The actually, i want to display list of the day at table from 1-30 april 2018. After i subtact the date, the date will become 1-31 mac 2018. i want to know if you have appropriate condition or formula for this date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NEXT_MONTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061962.html) and [FIRST_DAY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061474.html) to find out when a specific month starts. Moreover, Db2 supports date and time arithmetics. Just add or subtract days, weeks, months, years...

```
values(next_month('2018-04-16') - 1 day)
=> 2018-04-30
```

Comment: i'm not understand your code. Can you update your code from my where clause condition because i'm use the razor?

Comment: You need to write the query yourself. This is just showing how to use a function and date arithmetics.